# Structuring a Rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-activerecord, rails-models

How should I structure this Rails association?

**Problem**

So basically a user can create a dataset, and then create graphs off of it. I want the user to be able to create a project, and tag datasets or graphs with multiple projects. If a dataset is tagged with a project, it should not automatically tag all the graphs that belong to it (the dataset).

I'm a bit of a Rails association noob. Reading through the docs it sounds like I could do something like this.

1. "dataset" has_many "graphs".
2. "project" has_many "datasets" and "graphs".
3. "dataset" has_many "projects".
4. "graph" has_many "projects".

**Solution: (is this correct?)**

4 models: `Dataset, Graph, Project, ProjectContent`

For #1:

```
Dataset has_many Graphs
Graph belongs_to Dataset
```

For #2:

```
Project has_many datasets, through: :project_content
Project has_many graphs, through: :project_content
```

For #3:

```
Dataset has_many projects, through: project_content
```

For #4:

```
Graph has_many projects, through: project_content
```

Comment: Could you clarify: If you have a project, can you tag graphs for it even though you didn't tag the associated dataset?
For example: dataset1 has graph1, dataset2 has graph2. project1 tagged dataset1 and graph2.

Comment: yes exactly @Chai :) each item is assigned one at a time to a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This yells out "Polymorphic" to me, pretty much the default use case ;)

Tag Model:

```
belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
belongs_to :project
```

---

Project Model:

```
has_many :tags
has_many :datasets, :through => :tags, :source => :taggable, :source_type => 'Dataset'
has_many :graphs, :through => :tags, :source => :taggable, :source_type => 'Graph'
```

---

Graph Model:

```
belongs_to :dataset
has_many :tags, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :projects, :as => :taggable
```

---

Dataset Model:

```
has_many :graphs
has_many :tags, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :projects, :as => :taggable
```

If you do NOT want to go with a polymorphic model, your approach seems correct.

Comment: Thanks Chai, not sure I'm seeing what polymorphic gives me over my current model though

Comment: With only two taggable types: nothing :) Maybe one day a project will have many different kind of tags... XD